# Guide on installing MySQL server

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, mobile, production

I am working on a small company and still new to production of a mobile application. I am currently building a mobile application using .net web api and I have decided to use MySQL as my database and may i ask is it correct if I just install MySQL server on my windowns laptop? or is there any machine that i need to buy for the installation to make sure the production of the apps work well.

Examples of result I found just guide me on installing the server on my own laptop and I am not sure is it a right way for the production.

Comment: Hope someone can guide me on some steps.

Comment: Please remove SQL Server tag. SQL Server is not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

For development, I would suggest you to install MySQL in your local machine . There is many approach that would work well for you.

- Directly install MySQL to your machine
- Install Docker and have a MySQL image running whenever development is needed . It is also a good opportunity for learning as well
- A development server on the Cloud is also nice, if you have the budget for that

For production, it could be just a simple installation on your on-premise server, or any Cloud service provider ( AWS/GCP/Azure) that has MySQL as database would do

Comment: If i want to use on-premise server, is it ok for me to buy any desktop to install the server?